# Flutter: Getting below Exception , while accepting the location permissions

Tags: flutter, permissions, location

java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsClient, but class was expected (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsClient' appears in /data/app/~~vK3x6kuSR8MsWIHWo0p-pg==/com.wst.occser-5pgr4NMzu9vj5rO5C1Dcew==/base.apk!classes3.dex)
E/AndroidRuntime(15597):        at com.lyokone.location.FlutterLocation.startRequestingLocation(FlutterLocation.java:422)
E/AndroidRuntime(15597):        at com.lyokone.location.FlutterLocation.onRequestPermissionsResultHandler(FlutterLocation.java:131)
E/AndroidRuntime(15597):        at com.lyokone.location.FlutterLocation.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterLocation.java:122)
E/AndroidRuntime(15597):        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry$FlutterEngineActivityPluginBinding.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.java:777)
E/AndroidRuntime(15597):        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.java:409)
E/AndroidRuntime(15597):        at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:757)
E/AndroidRuntime(15597):        at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragment.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterFragment.java:915)
E/AndroidRuntime(15597):        at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterFragmentActivity.java:549)
E/AndroidRuntime(15597):        at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:8619)
E/AndroidRuntime(15597):        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8476)
E/AndroidRuntime(15597):        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5560)
E/AndroidRuntime(15597):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5606)
E/AndroidRuntime(15597):        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:54)
E/AndroidRuntime(15597):        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
E/AndroidRuntime(15597):        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(15597):        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(15597):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2374)
E/AndroidRuntime(15597):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(15597):        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
E/AndroidRuntime(15597):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
E/AndroidRuntime(15597):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8248)
E/AndroidRuntime(15597):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(15597):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:589)
E/AndroidRuntime(15597):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1071)
E/Parcel  (15597): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
I/Quality (15597): SlowBinder: com.wst.occser to android.app.IActivityManager cost= 284 code= 7
I/Process (15597): Sending signal. PID: 15597 SIG: 9

Using Android 13 device, location plugin ^4.4.0, firebase_messaging ^14.1.2

Comment: Did you find a solution for this as I have the same issue.

Comment: Raised it with the plugin at https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation/issues/800

Answer (score 5):

This issue originates from the [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) plugin which is referencing an older version of the google play services plugin.

To solve this issue, you need to update the version of "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location" inside the location package

[image: How to locate location version]

Change the dependency
from "api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16+'"

to "api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'"

Finally, save and rebuild project

Comment: How to see Flutter Plugins group like that in Android Studio?

Comment: In the Task Window, ensure you're on the Project view, Then you should see the following dropdown

External Libraries >> Flutter Plugins >> location-4.4.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually edit `Android/build.gradle` file inside local copy of location package. Packages are hosted inside pub cache folder. Full path to the folder: `flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-4.3.0/`

Replace this line:

api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+'

With this:

api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'

Note: You may have multiple versions of that package there. You need to find out which one your project is currently using and edit that one.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0'
```

and rerun the app.

Answer (score 0):

update your location the plugin and its auto update

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add this lines to your **android/app/build.gradle**

```
    configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
     
    }
  }

   

    dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
    }
```